# Vertical stacked bar chart with chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

Excellent and free library from [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). I'm transferring my charts from Google charts to chart.js, because I can use them offline and it seems more responsive to window's changes of size. Furthermore I realised that my viewers in China could not see my Google charts because Google services are blocked in China.

I've been reading the documentation regarding [stacked vertical bar charts](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart), but I can't figure out, how to make a chart like this. In all examples I saw for stacked bar charts, the number of items is the same for each bar.

Can I make only two vertical stacked datasets? It's because the right bar has more items than the left one. Or do I need `n` datasets, being `n` the number of items, of the bar which has more items?

[image]

### Code

I want to group one dataset per (stacked) bar, but I can't.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext('2d');
    
var labels = ["standing costs", "running costs"];
var dataset = [ 
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: ["cost1", "cost2", "cost3", "cost4"],
                  data: [1, 2, 1, 3],                       
                  stack: "standing costs",
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'navy',
                      'blue',
                      'aqua',
                      'teal'
                  ]
                },
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: ["cost5", "cost6", "cost7", "cost8"],
                  data: [5, 1, 3, 0],                       
                  stack: "running costs",
                  backgroundColor: [                         
                      'green',
                      'lime',
                      'yellow',
                      'white'
                  ]
                }
            ];

var options = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
};

var content = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: dataset
    },
    options
};

new Chart(ctx, content);
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/colors/1.0/colors.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Quick Solution :**

### Vertical Stacked Bar Chart

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Standing costs', 'Running costs'], // responsible for how many bars are gonna show on the chart
      // create 12 datasets, since we have 12 items
      // data[0] = labels[0] (data for first bar - 'Standing costs') | data[1] = labels[1] (data for second bar - 'Running costs')
      // put 0, if there is no data for the particular bar
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Washing and cleaning',
         data: [0, 8],
         backgroundColor: '#22aa99'
      }, {
         label: 'Traffic tickets',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#994499'
      }, {
         label: 'Tolls',
         data: [0, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#316395'
      }, {
         label: 'Parking',
         data: [5, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#b82e2e'
      }, {
         label: 'Car tax',
         data: [0, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#66aa00'
      }, {
         label: 'Repairs and improvements',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#dd4477'
      }, {
         label: 'Maintenance',
         data: [6, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#0099c6'
      }, {
         label: 'Inspection',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#990099'
      }, {
         label: 'Loan interest',
         data: [0, 3],
         backgroundColor: '#109618'
      }, {
         label: 'Depreciation of the vehicle',
         data: [0, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#109618'
      }, {
         label: 'Fuel',
         data: [0, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#dc3912'
      }, {
         label: 'Insurance and Breakdown cover',
         data: [4, 0],
         backgroundColor: '#3366cc'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: {
         position: 'right' // place legend on the right side of chart
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            stacked: true // this should be set to make the bars stacked
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            stacked: true // this also..
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" width="700"></canvas>
```

<sub>apology for not giving explanation.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a LOT. But kindly re-see my original post. Is there a way to group a dataset for each stacked bar? There is a [dataset property `stack`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart) which I think is for that, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: That property is for group stacked bar chart. something like [this](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/300494/15579306/6725ba42-23a7-11e6-9412-b3f5544b6e0e.png). But from your question, it doesn't seem you want something similar to that, or do you? also, that has some flaws to it, as it's not properly supported to ChartJS.

Comment: you're right, no, it's exactly how you depicted here. Thanks a lot. I will use your code. In any case, my suggestion might be an issue for improvement for the next version. What do you think? Shall I open an issue in github, or it's unnecessary?

Comment: I think it's unnecessary, as that's not how ChartJS works. Though you can submit if you wish, to see what they say.

Comment: ok, just a last question :) Any particular reason to put `responsive: false` in options?

Comment: to visualize the chart properly, otherwise it'll be shrank *(not always tho)*

Comment: Nice of them to default the documentation to `Development (master)` instead of the current stable release `2.9.4`.

Comment: this does not stack...

Comment: This is good, Can I have the two stacked bar under same label to compare the last two year data.? @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ I really need it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

**updated for v3**

```
<div style="height: 500px">
<canvas id="chart_1" ></canvas>
</div>
<script>

chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart_1').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Blue',
                data: [100, 110, 120],
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
            },
            {
                label: 'Red',
                data: [30, 20, 10],
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Example',
                font: {
                    size: 14
                }
            },
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```